# C++ member variable initialization, but first do some work inside it

Tags: c++, class, object

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    public: 
        MyClass(string something);
        ~MyClass();
    private:
        some_namespace::some_class_name my_variable_name;
};
```

with the following constructor definition:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string path) {
    string other = "jwrhkfg";
    my_variable_name = some_namespace::some_class_name(path+other)
}
```

I'm trying to initialize `my_variable_name` to something dependent on `path`. I know I could use initializer list:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string path) : my_variable_name(path+other) {}
```

But what if I need to do a lot of processing on top of the `path` string and then initialize `my_variable_name`? What if I need to do something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string path) {
    string other = "jwrhkfg";

    if (path="site.com") {
        other = "oritrot";
    } else {
        other = "hsghkr";
    }

    my_variable_name = some_namespace::some_class_name(path+other)
}
```

I cannot put these `if`s in an initializer list.

I thought the code above would work because I only declared the name `my_variable_name` but didn't define it, so I could do in the constructor, but when I do:

```
MyClass my_object = MyClass("some_string");
```

I get that there's no constructor for `some_class_name` (because the default constructor takes one argument, and here it is trying to initialize even if I didn't initialize it, only declared.

Comment: You're completely missing the point of a [constructor list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).  Please read the linked article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your member a smart pointer instead:

```
class MyClass {
    public: 
        MyClass(string something);
        ~MyClass();
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<some_namespace::some_class_name> my_variable_name;
};

MyClass:MyClass(string path) {
    string other = "jwrhkfg";
    my_variable_name = std::make_unique<some_namespace::some_class_name>(path+other);
}
```

Comment: Why it works for the object "unique_ptr" but not for my type of object? What's the difference?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is a wrapper around `some_namespace::some_class_name*`. It's default constructor initializes it with a `nullptr`.

Comment: Wouldn't the creation of MyClass my_object call unique_ptr's consctructor with no arguments?

Comment: I understand. The default constructor for no arguments will be called. If some_class_name had a constructor with no arguments it'd work too. Nice. But why c++ automatically initiates all objects I declare? Its so different from Java...

Comment: @MargarethReena that is, essentially, because no other types than pointers can be `NULL` (or `nullptr`) in C++. In Java, you can instantiate an object to be `null` (and implicitly do so if you don't assign a value on declaration), where as in C++ that is not possible without pointers.

Comment: So it'd also work if I did  some_namespace::some_class_name* my_variable_name; in the declaration, and then defined it in the constructor with a null? Why you tell me to use unique_ptr?

Comment: Yep, you are correct! AFAIK Java mostly operates references, so you can manually control your object creation (since any reference can be NULL). In C++, pointers behave in the similar fashion.

Comment: A smart pointer will automatically release the allocated memory when `MyClass ` will die, so you do not have to write `delete my_variable_name` in the destructor. Additionally, it initialize it's internal pointer to `nullptr` by default. This is less error-prone, since when doing all that manually you might forget to initialize a pointer (and end up with a pointer to garbage memory), or forget to `delete` it (and end up with a memory leak).

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Overkill. Ternary operator or function should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot put these ifs in an initialization list.

You can use a function to determine the value and use that in the initialization list:

```
string MyClass::getOther(string path) {
     if (path == "site.com") {
         return "oritrot";
     }
     return "hsghkr";
}

MyClass::MyClass(string path) : my_variable_name(path + getOther(path)) {
}
```

Also a ternary conditional would work for your simple case:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string path) 
: my_variable_name(path + (path == "site.com")?"oritrot":"hsghkr") {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to create a separate function to be used in intitialization list only, you can use lambdas:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string path)
    : my_variable_name(
        [&]() -> some_namespace::some_class_name
        {
        // do work here and return desired value
            string other = "jwrhkfg";

            if (path="site.com") {
                other = "oritrot";
            } else {
                other = "hsghkr";
            }
            return some_namespace::some_class_name(path+other);
        }() /*call lambda immediately*/ )
{}
```

Although it's true, that you can use ternary expression is this case (as pointed by user0042), approach with lambda is more generic and can be applicable in case of any complex initialization.